# Use paired or unpaired t-test to determine whether the difference in temperature means is statistically significant?

Tags: python, statistics, analysis, t-test

I am doing an analysis on whether there is a meaningful difference between the temperature in June and December in Hawaii. I first identify the average temperature in June at all stations across all available years in the dataset. I did the same for December temperature. Now I have average temperatures for both june and december between the years of 2010-2017, shown below:

- The average temperature in June 2010 is 74.9908 F
- The average temperature in June 2011 is 73.9024 F
- The average temperature in June 2012 is 74.0888 F
- The average temperature in June 2013 is 74.6405 F
- The average temperature in June 2014 is 75.0717 F
- The average temperature in June 2015 is 75.0356 F
- The average temperature in June 2016 is 75.1348 F
  ———————————————————————————
- The average temperature in December 2010 is 73.125 F
- The average temperature in December 2011 is 68.75 F
- The average temperature in December 2012 is 70.1667 F
- The average temperature in December 2013 is 73.1667 F
- The average temperature in December 2014 is 71.625 F
- The average temperature in December 2015 is 73.6 F
- The average temperature in December 2016 is 73.7143 F

I now have to use a t-test to determine whether the difference in the means, if any, is statistically significant. Will I use a paired t-test, or an unpaired t-test? Why?

I am unclear whether to use a paired or unpaired t-test. I know paired should be used for similar samples taken at different times (i.e. rat tumor size before and after treatment). However, I am confused because the variable temperature is taken at two different times (June and December) at the same location (the average temperature recorded at all stations in Hawaii). I am confused as to which t-test I use for this example and why I use it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a question for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), the exchange for statistics.

That being said, at first glance, either type of t-test would suffice for a simple analysis. Using a paired t-test would account for variation in temperatures across years (at least to some degree). Average temperatures and years are surely correlated.